# Use if else endif in html comments

Tags: php, html

I wounder about using php function eg. if, else, endif in html comments. This is my example code:

```
<!-- if 1 == 1 -->
 Is equal
 <!-- else -->
 Not equal
 <!-- endif -->
```

My php file convert this comment to:

```
<!-- ?> if (1 == 1) <?php -->
```

Is this method safe to using it? Is there any way to view html file with this comments from any users?

Comment: looks like you should consider a template engiine

Comment: The code it results in is invalid. I think you mean `<?php if (1 == 1) ?>` ?

Comment: @GolezTrol Because I have start tag <?php in index.php which one has include other files

Comment: instead of asking how to make a certain nonsensical syntax that won't work work, tell us what you're actually trying to do so we *can* answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a smart idea to display PHP code into HTML Comments. I would strongly advise not to do this because you might expose valuable application logic to unknown users.

The question however is, why do you want to use PHP code into HTML comments?

- If you want to use it to help yourself developing, it might be better to just write pseudo code.
- If you want to have actually php code into your help file, then you don't need to put it in HTML comments. Something like this:

  ```
  <?php if (1 == 1): ?>
      Yes, 1 is equal to 1! Awesome
      place rest of html code here for example.
  <?php else: ?>
      No, 1 is not equal to 1
  <?php endif; ?>
  ```

Comment: Why not? PHPBB use this case in own script as well.